# Funcion reversed, sorted en python

Tags: python

Quiero oredenar una lista por cantidad de letras, de menor a mayor, y a igual cantidad de letras y alfabeticamente .
Devolver la lista ordenada.

```
def palabras_ordenadas(lista):
    for palabra in reversed(sorted(lista, key =len)
         return palabra
```

Comment: La lista es una lista de cadenas `["hola", "que", "tal", "estás"]`? Si es así debería quedar ordenada como `[ "que", "tal", "hola", "estás"]`?

Comment: paso una lista y la tengo que ordenar de menor a mayor segun la cantidad de caracteres y si tiene la misma cantidad de letras , lo ordeno alfabeticanente.. si como en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Un par de observaciones:

- En tu función iteras sobre la salida de `reversed` con un `for` pero dentro del mismo usas `return`. Esto hace que en la primera iteración la función retorne, devolviendo solo la primera palabra. Lo más lógico es que te retorne una nueva lista con las palabras ordenadas.
- Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que `list.sort/sorted` tiene un parámetro llamado `reversed` que te permite invertir el orden sin necesidad de recurrir a `reversed()`. En cualquier caso esto no es necesario en tu caso dado que requieres un ordenamiento descendente para ambos casos.

Tienes varias posibilidades, una de ellas es usar tu propia función para permitir ordenar en una sola pasada:

```
def palabras_ordenadas(lista):
    return sorted(lista, key=lambda palabra: (len(palabra), palabra))
```

el truco está en que por cada palabra la función anónima retorna una tupla en la que el primer elemento es un entero representando la longitud de dicha palabra y el segundo es la propia palabra. De esta forma `sorted` ordena las palabras según las tuplas, primero atendiendo al primer elemento (enteros) y si coincide ordena de acuerdo al segundo, cadenas (lexicográficamene), es decir, para la lista:

```
['yo', 'que', 'tal', 'bien', 'hola', 'estás']
```

lo que usa para ordenar realmente (`key`) es:

```
(4, 'hola'), (3, 'que'), (3, 'tal'), (5, 'estás'), (2, 'yo'), (4, 'bien')
```

que quedaría:

```
(2, 'yo'), (3, 'que'), (3, 'tal'), (4, 'bien'), (4, 'hola'), (5, 'estás')
```

Alternativamente puedes prescindir de `lambda` y usar una función con nombre "normal":

```
def palabras_ordenadas(lista):
    def sort_key(palabra):
        return len(palabra), palabra
    return sorted(lista, key=sort_key)
```

Otra posibilidad es llamar dos veces a `sorted` o `list.sort`, ordenando primero lexicogáficamente, dado que en caso de que al ordenar por longitud dos palabras coincidan, se mantendrá el orden original (lexicográfico). Por esto se dice que `sorted/list.sort` es [estable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento#Estabilidad):

```
def palabras_ordenadas(lista):
    lista = sorted(lista)
    lista.sort(key=len)
    return lista
```

> ```
> >>> ord_list = palabras_ordenadas(["hola", "que", "tal", "estás", "yo", "bien"])
> >>> ord_list
> ['yo', 'que', 'tal', 'bien', 'hola', 'estás']
> ```

También puedes ordenar la lista in-place, en cuyo caso no debes retornar nada. PAra ello simplemente usa `list.sort` en vez de `sorted`:

```
def palabras_ordenadas(lista):
    lista.sort(key=lambda palabra: (len(palabra), palabra))
```

> ```
> >>> lista = ["hola", "que", "tal", "estás", "yo", "bien"]
> >>> palabras_ordenadas(lista)  
> >>> print(lista) 
> ['yo', 'que', 'tal', 'bien', 'hola', 'estás']
> ```

Comment: Estupenda respuesta. Disculpa, tan solo, que te diga que no hay que confundir _lambda_ con una _función anónima_, a pesar de la opinión generalizada. La evaluación de lambda se realiza por sustitución, mientras que una función se evalua en su propia clausura.

Answer (score 1):

A `sorted()` debes pasarle en `key` una función que será aplicada a cada elemento de la lista para producir otro dato que será el que se use en las comparaciones de cara a su ordenación.

En tu ejemplo has puesto `key=len`, lo que implica que se usará `len()` sobre cada dato de la lista y será el resultado de esa función la que se usará para ordenar. No obstante, en caso de empate en `len()` Python elegirá arbitrariamente cómo desempatar (seguramente por el orden que tenían originalmente en la lista) por lo que tu código sólo resuelve parte del problema (aparte de que usas `reversed()` no sé por qué, ya que querías la lista de menor a mayor y no al revés, y de que retornas una palabra en vez de la lista ordenada).

Por otro lado sabemos que en Python una tupla se compara con otra comparando primero el primer elemento de ambas, y si son iguales comparando entonces el segundo elemento etc.

Esto nos da una idea para resolver tu problema. Si la función que pasas a `key` devuelve una tupla cuyo primer elemento es la longitud de la palabra y el segundo elemento es la propia palabra, entonces en caso de empate en longitud (primer elemento) se usará el segundo (la propia palabra, y por tanto el orden alfabétido).

Así pues la idea sería:

```
ordenada = sorted(lista, key=lambda palabra: (len(palabra), palabra))
```

Finalmente, dices que debes retornar la lista ordenada. Pero tu código hace un `return` de la primera palabra que encuentra al iterar por el bucle. Para retornar una lista ordenada no debes iterar, sino simplemente retornar el valor de `ordenada`.